# Question regarding Pandas dataframe column names when using value_counts()

Tags: pandas

I am using df.'columnname'.value_counts() .

Having trouble when the column name in the dataframe has name like 'Status Test'.

I get an error when the column name is more than one word.

What is solution here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting a column with what's called "dot notation" (e.g. selecting a column how you have in the question: `df.column_name`). You'll need to select a column with "bracket notation" where you pass the column name as a string into indexing brackets: `df["column name"]` When we use this selection method, you're able to accommodate spaces in column names.

For a complete snippet:`df["Status Test"].value_counts()` should give you the desired result.